# Prove that Sequence $\phi _n(x)=n\phi(nx)$ is delta sequence

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $\phi : \Bbb R \to [0, \infty)$ be such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi (x) dx=1 $. Define $\phi _n(x)=n\phi(nx)$. Show that $\{\phi _n(x)\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a delta sequence.

Attempt: To show this I need to show

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\phi_n,\psi)=(\delta,\psi)=\psi(0), \quad \forall \psi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}).$$

$(\phi_n,\psi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\phi(nx)\psi(x)dx.$

After Substitution $y=nx$, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\phi(nx)\psi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(y)\psi\left(\frac{y}{{n}}\right)dy.$
After that I dont know, what have to do.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: let $f_n\colon y\mapsto \phi\left(y\right)\psi\left(y/n\right)$.

- What is the pointwise limit of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$?
- Can you bound $\left\lvert f_n(y)\right\rvert$ by a quantity independent of $n$ and integrable in $y$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

For all $y$ $\phi(y) \psi \left( \frac{y}{n}\right) \rightarrow \phi(y) \psi(0)$ and use **dominated convergence theorem**.

Comment: $\psi \in \mathcal{D}(\Bbb R)$ so $|\phi(y) \psi \left( \frac {y}{n} \right) |\leq \|\psi\|_\infty |\phi(y)| \in L^1 $